# How to check if readUTF method has some value to receive or not

Tags: java, sockets

I am implementing a server client application in java. 
Situation is that client sends some message to server and server may or may not respond(send back some message).

---

Have a look at this

`is = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());`

Now i am using `is.readUTF();` method to get the message back.

**Problem is that** readUTF is a blocking call and it stops the program right there to receive a message.
As i said that server may or may not respond and i need a way to stop the readUTF method from stopping the program(checking if there is a message or not) and keep on continue if there is no message received.

Comment: Make the server respond in any case. Also, if the client can continue before receiving the answer, communicate in a second thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataInputStream.available()` to check whether there is data to be read and wrap the socket's `InputSteam` with a `PushbackInputStream` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982693/available-of-datainputstream-from-socket).